# How to add all status in filter in backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

[image]

I have added a dropdown filter in backpack for laravel,
The first option in the dropdown is `-`.
Now I want to change this text to `All Status`.
I mean when no filter option is selected, the default option is now `-`, I want to make this `all Status`.

Answer (score 2):

at the moment the only way to do it is by overwriting the filter blade file in your resources folder since  `-` is an hardcoded string.
It means `filter clear`, like an empty option, and not `Show all something`. Show all something is `on by default` when nothing is selected in the filter, so the `-` means that the filter is not beeing applied, no filter option selected.

Feel free to open an issue as a `Feature Request` if you think diferent way, maybe you are right and we are wrong, it happened alot of times. :)

Cheers